# Detect whether iphone is of notch screen or normal rectangle screen to avaid navigation bar size issue?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, iphone-x

I am facing an issue in implementing expandable banner on top like whatsapp do in profile screen. When user scroll image squeezes and convert into navigation bar. For that i have to set minimum height in my code but due to notch screen in iphone X and other new iphones it causing issue. Because old iphone doesnot have notch screen so there navigation bar height is less than new iphones?

So there is any way to find out the iphone is notch screen or normal type screen?

Comment: You can set constraint with respect to safe area so it will adjust automatically if  device it iPhone X or new one.

Comment: no brother, what you have told actually makes top small notch part untouched and open with default color of iOS.i want  my banner image to cover top notch part. Anyways thanx @Pankaj

Comment: Not quite sure from your description what the final result you would like is but I believe Pankaj's point is correct. Using a mixture of the top anchor and top safe area anchor should give you what you want. The danger in trying to do things yourself using "hasNotch" is that Apple almost certainly are going to break you. All they have to do is change the size of the notch. If you expand on what you want to achieve you might get a better suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

This way you can detect notch screen:

```
extension UIDevice {
    var hasNotch: Bool {
        let bottom = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 0
        return bottom > 0
    }
}

if UIDevice.current.hasNotch {
            // consider notch
        } else {
            // don't have to consider notch
        }
```